# MaterialUI KeyboardDateTimePicker: change background color without changing spacing inside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, background-color, styling

I'm trying to change the background color on `KeyboardDateTimePicker` components, but however I noticed that when I add `style={{background: "rgb(232, 241, 250)"}}` background property to override the background color and I have `inputVariant="filled"` on this element, the background color seems to be mixing up and become darker than it is supposed to be. To resolve this problem I had to remove `inputVariant="filled"`, I got the correct color this way but then padding between the text and component elements became incorrect (everything has shifted to the left top corner). How would I set background color with the correct RGB values without messing up the padding on the elements inside the component?

```
export function InquiryDateTimePicker(props: InquiryDateTimePickerProps) {
  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDateTimePicker
            // inputVariant="filled"
            style={{background: "rgb(232, 241, 250)"}}
            size="small"
            readOnly={true}
            fullWidth={true}
            format="yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm"
            id="time-picker"
            label="Дата поступления"
            value={props.selectedDate}
            onChange={() => {}}
            KeyboardButtonProps={{
                'aria-label': 'change time',
            }}
        />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
);}
```

[image: issue screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override styles for FilledInput:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiFilledInput: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: 'unset'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

and put your component in Theme Provider:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <InquiryDateTimePicker />
</ThemeProvider>
```